# set image wallpaper to fit screen "

Tags: java, android

I want to set the image to fit all screen when the user makes it as background for his device, I tried many codes but it does not work.
Here is my code

```
item_home_image = findViewById(R.id.item_home_image);
item_home_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            String url = intent.getStringExtra("imageUrl");
            Picasso.with(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this).load(url).into(new Target() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this);
                    try {
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toasty.normal(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "تم تغيير الخلفية بنجاح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    Toasty.error(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "فشل تحميل الصورة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    Toasty.normal(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "جاري التحميل", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: set `ImageView` Atttribute `scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: @Joker I updated the question to know what i mean

Comment: you need to scale that image as displaySize

Comment: please check the answer may those helps you

Comment: Thank you all of u, what if I want to make the image responds to the screen and maintains its content like Zedge app for example, when u set pic as wallpaper it is responds to the screen and maintains its content no matter how different the screen size is. @Joker

Comment: take a look at this video please, it describes what I mean, https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=FiU-uxBjQSA&app=desktop, first one is my app, second is Zedge app, same photo " video is just 14sec" @Joker

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true); 

try {
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(newBitmap);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to make the image responds to the screen and maintains its content like Zedge app, for example, when u set pic as wallpaper it is responding to the screen and maintains its content no matter how different the screen size is

Comment: Can't get what you mean by 'make the image respond and maintain its content'. Is your image scrolling now and you want it fixed? Or its the other way around? Or you mean something else?

Comment: take a look at this video please, it describes what I mean, https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=FiU-uxBjQSA&app=desktop, first one is my app, second is Zedge app, same photo " video is just 14sec"

Answer (score 1):

The bitmap that are you setting with `wallpaperManager` may not same as the **Display size** so, you need to scale that bitmap before passing to `wallpaperManager`

Try With

```
item_home_image = findViewById(R.id.item_home_image);
item_home_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            String url = intent.getStringExtra("imageUrl");
            Picasso.with(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this).load(url).into(new Target() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this);
                    try {
                        int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels; 
                        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true); 
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toasty.normal(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "تم تغيير الخلفية بنجاح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    Toasty.error(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "فشل تحميل الصورة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    Toasty.normal(PicassoDisplayImageAdapter.this, "جاري التحميل", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ImageView attributes

```
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

more [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType#summary)